# have 2 tables employee and branch, need to show salary expense grouped by branch name. How do I join these tables showing branch_name and total salary

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

```
(
    SELECT DISTINCT employee.branch_id, branch.branch_name
    FROM employee
    JOIN branch
    ON employee.branch_id = branch.branch_id
 ) ;

SELECT employee.branch_id, SUM(salary)
FROM employee
GROUP BY employee.branch_id;
```

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(40),
    last_name VARCHAR(40),
    birth_day DATE,
    sex VARCHAR(1),
    salary INT,
    super_id INT,
    branch_id INT
); 

CREATE TABLE branch (
    branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    branch_name VARCHAR(40),
    mgr_id INT,
    mgr_start_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: hi, can you show the CREATE TABLE statements for the tables `employee`, `branch`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE employee (
  emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(40),
  last_name VARCHAR(40),
  birth_day DATE,
  sex VARCHAR(1),
  salary INT,
  super_id INT,
  branch_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE branch (
  branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  branch_name VARCHAR(40),
  mgr_id INT,
  mgr_start_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);

Comment: in employee table salaries are given with branch_id as the foreign key referencing to primary key of branch table. I am able to crack query for grouping by branch_id in employee table but I want to show the names of the branches which is in branch table, how do I join that

Answer (score 2):

You only need to combine your two queries

Test playground: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/34jwEhEzywdHKU2iEMeyCy/0

```
SELECT 
  branch_name,
  SUM(salary)
FROM employee 
JOIN branch  ON employee.branch_id = branch.branch_id
GROUP BY employee.branch_id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot friend, I am just a beginner so got confused

Comment: hope it works for you buddy!  good luck and be well